# Maximization of Differential Entropy (Optimization Problem)

Tags: optimization, information-theory, entropy

I'm trying to solve the following optimization problem:

$$\underset{f:[-A,A]\to\mathbb{R^+}}{\mathrm{argmin}}\left\{\int_{-A}^{A}f(u)\log_2[f(u)]\ \mathrm{d}u\right\}\qquad\mathrm{s.t.}\ \int_{-A}^{A}f(u)\ \mathrm{d}u=1$$

In other words - I am trying to find the PMF $f(u)$ of a random variable $U\in[-A,A]$ that maximizes the differential entropy. I am aware that the solution is a uniform random variable; i.e. $f(u)=1/2A$. I somehow managed to get to this solution - my attempt was Euler Lagrange Equations - defining the Lagrangian:

$$\mathcal{L}[f]\equiv f(u)\log_2[f(u)]+\lambda\left[\frac{1}{2A}-f(u)\right]$$

One gets:

$$0=\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial f(u)}-\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}u}\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial f'(u)}=\log_2[f(u)]+\frac{1}{\ln(2)}-\lambda\implies f(u)=\mathrm{const}$$

And then of course, the constant must be $1/2A$ (due to the normalization constraint). However, I'm not sure if this solution is correct, and overall, I don't think I'm allowed to use Euler Lagrange Equations for this.

Thanks!

Comment: This looks fine to me (up to arguing that the $f$ you've found is the maximum --- E-L only tells you local extrema --- but the concavity should make that obvious). Why do you think you cannot use the Euler Lagrange Equations here?

Comment: An alternative is to use Gibbs' inquality - if we let $u$ be the uniform law on $[-A,A]$, and $p$ be any other law on this interval, then notice that $$ D(p\| u) = -h(p) + \log(2A) \iff h(p) = \log(2A) - D(p\|u).$$ So, to maximise $h(p),$ you need to minimise this KL divergence, but this obviously happens when $p = u.$